# Why do we have to sum the expansions around all the action's stationary points?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, semiclassical, instantons, non-perturbative

This is in some sense a follow-up question to my previous question [Why is it OK to keep the quadratic term in the small $\hbar$ approximation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/272864/). I understand how we can expand the action around a stationary point. This way we obtain a semiclassical expansion. I have read it in Coleman's Aspects of Symmetry that "If there are several stationary points, in general one has to sum over all of them".

I do not see why. I mean, we can always make the expansio around the stationary point of our choosing, isn't it? why do we have to sum all the expansions?

Comment: The path integral is taken over all paths. If you throw away the parts that are not stationary as not contributing, you are left with a sum over stationary paths.

Answer (score 5):

1. A [path integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) is in principle a weighted sum over all possible histories. Its precise mathematical definition is in general an open problem. A path integral is typically evaluated as an instanton sum
   $$Z~=~\sum_j Z_j ,\tag{1}$$
   where each [instanton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instanton) $\phi_j$ has a fluctuation path integral
   $$Z_j~:=~\int\!{\cal D}\eta~ \exp\left\{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\phi_j\!+\!\eta]\right\} \tag{2}$$
   that is viewed as a perturbative expansion in $\hbar$.
2. Now OP is essentially pondering if the instanton sum (1) amounts to overcounting the histories? The answer is *No,* because starting from one instanton sector, all other instantons are non-perturbative effects, which cannot be reproduced with the perturbative fluctuation path integral (2). See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82585/2451) related Phys.SE post.